# What is this ASP.NET Tag <%= XXXX %>?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to edit a page based on ASP.NET. On the page I saw some tags like this:

```
"" <% = ClientConfigScript%> "" (not ")

"" <% = LanguageScript%> "" (not ")
```

Honestly I did not understand what they refer to in the code and how they are recalled.

Example:

```
<% = GetText ("button-x")%>
```

I discovered that it is going to take a field from an XML file, in this case of language `English.xml` but I can not find the call in the code.

Could someone explain to me what this syntax means and which file (js, xml) do they connect to?

Comment: Find the method GetText  in your solution, and see its implementation.
this section <% = means that you want to call server side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at WebForms syntax in the ASP.Net web framework that on server side execution creates a response.write statement to the client.

`<% %>` = embedded server side code block

`<%= %>` = response.write output on client

`<%# %>` = data bind

In your first two examples it is outputting the scripts that the page is using and the last item is likely setting the text of an element on the page, I'm going to guess a button's text.

You don't change this in a js/xml file (although you could change the button's text in JS but that is besides the point).

You will need to have access to the original project's page source to modify.

```
<%= GetText() %>
```

GetText is a function on the server side.  For example, if you have a page called MyForm you would look for a MyForm Controller or WebForm (if WebForms) in the project source.  You will find the GetText function in that class.

The syntax is older and is generally used in WebForms, not MVC (although the first few versions of MVC used this syntax).